# Quantile prediction for mlr3 graph learner

Tags: mlr3

I have a stacked learner where the output layer is a `regr.ranger` with params `list(rf.quantreg = TRUE, rf.keep.inbag = TRUE)`. Is it possible to predict quantiles with `GraphLearner`s like this?

I know that for a pure `lrn('regr.ranger')`, once trained, I can simply reference the `ranger` model directly and use that for quantile prediction:

```r
predict(my_learner$model, data = my_test_data, type = "quantiles", quantiles = c(0.025, 0.975))
```

But for the stacked learner, I have other learners mediating between the features and `regr.ranger`, so it seems to me that I *have* to go via `mlr3`.

My `GraphLearner` consists of some feature coding, a `regr.kknn` learner and a `regr.glm` learner plus some extras. Then `rf` (a `regr.ranger`) sits at the output level:

[image]